# Python's os.walk and case sensitivity on Ubuntu?

Tags: python, ubuntu-14.04, os.walk

I've got a bit of a strange situation that has me a bit stumped.  I'm trying to perform a file system search of all sub-directories of a specified path.  I want to return results, respecting the user's desire for a case-sensitive or case-insensitive search.  This seems to work fine on Windows, but is giving me a bit of a headache when running the same code on Python.

For the sake of testing things, I've stripped out some code of the main application into a small snippet of python code, like so:

```
import sys
import os

src = sys.argv[1]
caseSensitive = sys.argv[2]
searchText = sys.argv[3]

if caseSensitive == False:
    searchText = searchText.lower()

print "Case sensitive: " + caseSensitive
print "Src: " + src
print "Search text: " + searchText
fileCount = 0
directoryCount = 0;

if caseSensitive == True:
    print "Performing case sensitive search..."
else:
    print "Performing case insensitive search..."


for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(src):
    for directory in dirnames:
        if caseSensitive == True:
            dMatch = directory
        else:
            dMatch = directory.lower()

        print "D:" + dMatch
        if dMatch.find(searchText) != -1:
            print "    **************dir match: " + dMatch
            directoryCount = directoryCount + 1
    for filename in filenames:
        if caseSensitive == True:
            fMatch = filename
        else:
            fMatch = filename.lower()

        print "F:" + fMatch

        if fMatch.find(searchText) != -1:
            print "    **************file match: " + fMatch
            fileCount = fileCount + 1

print "Matching files: "
print fileCount
print "Matching directories: "
print directoryCount
```

It's a bit of a rough sample, but it at least gives a general idea of what I'm doing.

Suppose that I have a directory structure as follows:

```
Foo
  --bar
  --Fizz
     --Buzz
       --Buzz.txt
```

If I run the script and point it at the Foo directory, and tell it to do a case-sensitive search for the word "Bu", on Windows it will find the Buzz directory and Buzz.txt.

If I run the same snippet on Ubuntu, it won't return any results at all, unless I ignore the case.  When printing out the directories and file names that are encountered by os.walk(), it prints them all in lowercase.  This would partially explain why the search is failing when running on Ubuntu - it won't ever find a match because it is comparing a mixed case "Bu" against "bu", which won't register as a match.

Long story short: am I missing something, or are the results from os.walk() on Ubunut always returned in lower-case?

Comment: `caseSensitive` will be a string, it will never equal `False` or `True`.

Comment: As a side note, you almost never want to test `if caseSensitive == True:`. Normally you just want `if caseSensitive:`, so anything truthy counts. When you explicitly want to make sure that it's nothing but `True`, not anything else truthy, you almost always want `if caseSensitive is True:` (because, among other things, `1 == True` is true). See [PEP 8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations) for more details.

Comment: Anyway, this kind of problem is exactly why you want to look at the output of your `print` statements—and post your input and output here, because a lot of times it's hard to notice obvious things in your own code. If you see `Performing case sensitive search..." even though you used `False` as the argument, it would be immediately obvious that only the first few lines of code are relevant, because things have already gotten screwed up before you get to the `os.walk` bit.

Comment: Looks like you guys nailed it.  Of course this still doesn't help me track down the bug in production, but at least it gets my sample app working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, it wasn't a problem with os.walk at all (as pointed out by isedev and abarnert.  The problem is with a library that was being used in the production code.  In the production code, it was doing something like the following:

```
for root, dirnames, fileanmes in os.walk(src):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*' + searchText + '*'):
        # If we are case insensitive, compare against a lowercase filename
    for dirname in fnmatch.filter(dirnames, '*' + searchText + '*'):
        # If we are case insensitive, compare against a lowercase dirname
```

The problem we were seeing is because whatever fmatch was doing, it was failing.  In our particular situation, we really aren't dealing with more than half a dozen files or directories at any given time, so we replaced it as follows:

```
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(src):
    for filename in filenames:
        # Do comparison on all filenames, not some fancy filtered list
    for dirname in dirnames:
        # Do comparison on all dirnames, not some fancy filtered list
```

It would seem that, for whatever reason, the fnmatch library wasn't doing exactly what we thought it was doing.  What we thought it should have been doing was a wildcard style comparisons - and it was, at least on Windows.  When running the same code on Ubuntu, it wasn't finding matches like it should have.

Thanks for the help, folks.